# How to find MIN and MAX of each Column for a rdd using Map/Reduce or by any other method

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have read nearly 100 CSV files into one RDD

```
rdd=sc.textFile("file:///C:/Users\pinjala/Documents/Python Scripts/Files_1/*.csv")
```

I want to find Min and Max for each column in the RDD.Nearly 100 columns.

Can some one suggest how i can find Min and max for a RDD for different columns.

When I used 
`rdd.collect()`, I am able to see rdd as list containing column names in first element and values of each columns in rest of elements in a list.

```
rdd=sc.textFile("file:///C:/Users\pinjala/Documents/Python Scripts/Files_1/*.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you had given some sample data.
Anyway, i just simulated and here is code-

```
new_list = []
list_p = [['John',19,1,9,20,68],['Jack',3,2,5,12,99]] #list of tuple
rdd = sc.parallelize(list_p) #Build a RDD
print(rdd.collect()) # [['John', 19, 1, 9, 20, 68], ['Jack', 3, 2, 5, 12, 99]]
for p in list_p:
    header = p[0]
    p.remove(p[0]) 
    min_p = sc.parallelize(p).min()
    max_p = sc.parallelize(p).max()
    new_list.append("["+header+","+str(min_p)+","+str(max_p)+"]")
print(new_list) # ['[John,1,68]', '[Jack,2,99]']
```